# Best way to center a UILabel in a UITableViewCell that's dynamic in height?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm trying to place a UILabel directly in the middle of a UITableViewCell vertically. Essentially I'm doing something such as:

float yPos = self.contentView.center.y;

I then assign yPos to my UILabel and add it as a subview of self.contentView within my UITableView subclass.

This still doesn't appear to be smack in the middle of the cell.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float yPos = (CGRectGetHeight(self.contentView.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(label.frame)) / 2;
```

Comment: That's not quite correct - you're putting it at exactly the bottom there. It should be:
float yPos = self.contentView.center.y - (label.frame.size.height / 2) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Are you subtracting (height of UILabel / 2) from yPos?

Comment: I'm not... I wish there was a cheat sheet for this stuff. how should the math look?